# Calculating Value-at-Risk of a discrete random variable

Tags: probability

I'm completely stuck at one of the introductory examples for the Value-at-Risk concept in the book I'm using...

The VaR is defined in a following way-->

> For $\alpha \in \left< 0,1 \right>$, we define Value-at-Risk (VaR) of a random variable $X$, at confidence level $1-\alpha$, as $$\text{VaR}^{\alpha}(X)=-\inf \{ x : \alpha < F_X(x)\}.$$

In the example, the random variable is defined as
$$
X=
\begin{cases}
0,\ \text{with probability }p\\
1, \ \text{with probability }1-p\\
\end{cases},
$$
and then it is stated that for $p<\alpha$ we have
$$\text{VaR}^{\alpha}(X)=0.$$

Is this a typo? Shouldn't the actual $\text{VaR}^{\alpha}(X)$ be equal to -1?

I mean, is this -->
$$\{x : \alpha <F_X(x) \}=\left[ 1, +\infty \right>$$
correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're right, this is an error and your last equation is correct.

By the way, [Wikipedia's definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_at_risk#Mathematical_definition) doesn't have that minus sign before the infimum, and it doesn't make much sense to me.